# Plotting single-variable duration time series data with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a list of companies with a start and end date of an event. I want to plot a figure that displays the date on the x-axis and the count of companies currently undergoing the event on the y-axis. The only way I can think of doing this at the moment is generating a column for every day and giving it a 1/0 for whether or not that day is between the start and end date for every company, and then reshaping it. Is there a more efficient way to produce this?

Here's some example data:

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(id = sample(100:500, 100, replace = F))
df$start <- sample(seq(as.Date('2020/01/01'), as.Date('2020/12/31'), by="day"), 100)
df$end <- df$start + sample(1:50, replace = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option, though I doubt that it's much more efficient than what you're already doing.  It is also making all of the days and then identifying whether or not any particular observation is "active" that day.

```
outdf <- tibble(
  date = seq(min(df$start), max(df$end), by=1), 
  num = rowSums(outer(date, 
                      1:nrow(df), 
                      function(x,y)x > df$start[y] & x < df$end[y]))
)

outdf
# # A tibble: 404 x 2
#   date         num
#   <date>     <dbl>
# 1 2020-01-05     0
# 2 2020-01-06     1
# 3 2020-01-07     1
# 4 2020-01-08     1
# 5 2020-01-09     1
# 6 2020-01-10     1
# 7 2020-01-11     2
# 8 2020-01-12     2
# 9 2020-01-13     2
# 10 2020-01-14     2
# # … with 394 more rows
```